# Adding elements to a mat-tab-group element

Tags: angular, angular-material2

**Angular 5**

I want to implement a search bar in the header bar of a mat-tab-group element (i.e., the row where the tab names are present)

Is there any way to render an element (which is not a tab) or an image in a mat-tab-group element?

Comment: it's been more than an year since this question was posted. any luck with that?

Comment: @muhammadkashif sorry, I don't remember if I had fixed this and don't have access to the code anymore :/

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**

Add the margin to **mat-tab-body-wrapper** class (if you can't override in the component style sheet override it in the root style sheet) and fit the element using absolute position in the margin, this is the easy way and the advantage is you can apply the material directives as well.

```css
.mat-tab-body-wrapper {
    margin-top: 60px !important;
  }
```

**Option 2**

By following this method you can not add the material directives and setAttribute converts to lowercase, which i think can solve using namespace, but you still you can't use the data-binding, special characters like '[' etc with this methods.

You can add element using **Renderer2** class after the component view initialization. All though you can do the same using the JavaScript it is not recommended, as Renderer2 DOM manipulation will be handled by the angular and doesn't break.

**component.html**

```html
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="center" #navigationElement>
  <mat-tab label="Tab-A">A Body</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab-B">B Body</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab-c">C Body</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**component.ts**

```
export class HomeNavComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('navigationElement', { static: false }) navEl: any;

  constructor(private rendrer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {


    const searchElWrapper = this.rendrer.createElement('div');

    const searchInEl = this.rendrer.createElement('input');
    this.rendrer.setAttribute(searchInEl, 'placeholder', 'Search');
    this.rendrer.addClass(searchInEl, 'searchWrapper');
    this.rendrer.appendChild(searchElWrapper, searchInEl);

    const parentEl = this.navEl._elementRef.nativeElement;
    this.rendrer.insertBefore(parentEl, searchElWrapper, parentEl.childNodes[1]);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {

  }
}
```

Both the methods will give the following result, with static search bar on tab toggling as well.

[image]